# Keeping data in-sync with server

Tags: ajax, node.js, ember.js, express

This is my stack : Ember.js + Express/Node.js

Say i have an Endpoint as `\posts`, it will return an array of objects.

and i have following template named `allPosts` :

```
{{#each post in content}}
 <p>{{post.body}} </p>
{{/each}}
```

Route:

```
App.AllPosts =Ember.Object.extend({
  body : null
})

App.AllPostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController :  function(controller,model){
    controller.set('content',model);
  } 
});
```

And controller as

```
App.AllPostsController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    save : fucntion(){
      // Get And update data from server via ajax
    }
  }
});
```

I want to keep data in sync with data on server, for this i planned to use `setInterval` and call the `save` action above every 1000ms to update the data. But it doesn't work. i used `setInterval` like this

```
setInterval(App.AllPostsController.actions.save,3000);
```

I **DONT** want to use Ember Data. As the data is dependent on another Node app which runs server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to run an action on a type, not an instance of the controller. Instead you should start saving when you actually hit the route and controller, `setupController` is a good place to accomplish this.

```
App.AllPostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController :  function(controller,model){
    controller.set('content',model);  // in this code model would be blank, I'm assuming you're leaving out code
    this.startSaving(controller);
  },

  willTransition: function(transition){
    //if I'm leaving, this.stopSaving();
  },

  isSaving: false,
  startSaving: function(controller){
    this.set('isSaving', true);
    this.realSave(controller);
  },
  realSave: function(controller){
    if(!this.get('isSaving')) return;
    Em.run.later(function(){
      controller.send('save');
    }
  },
  stopSaving: function(){
    this.set('isSaving', false);
  }

});
```